# An elementary differential geometry proof

Tags: differential-geometry

> Given a differentiable function $k(s)$, $s\in I$, show that the parametrized plane curve having $k(s)=k$ as curvature is given by
>   $$ \alpha (s) = \left( \int \cos\theta(s)ds + a, \int \sin\theta(s)ds + b \right) $$
>   where $$ \theta(s)= \int k(s)ds + \varphi $$ and that the curve is determined up to a translation of the vector $(a,b)$ and a rotation of the angle $\varphi$.

This exercise is from Do Carmo *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*, section 1.5.
My problem is that I'm not even sure where to start. It is not clear for me what is required for this type of proofs. I mean, the proof is based on some constructive procedure? Or the usual way is, instead, start as "if such $\alpha$ exist, it must verify such and such..."

Answer (score 1):

You have to show two things. First, you have to show that the function $\alpha(s)$ *has* curvature $k(s)$. So compute the curvature of $\alpha$ and show that it turns out to be $k$.

Then you have to show that any other curve with the same curvature differs from $\alpha$ by a translation and rotation. One way of doing this is by writing down a differential equation that $\alpha$ must satisfy and appealing to uniqueness of solutions of second-order ODEs given initial conditions. The initial conditions will be the curve's starting point and initial velocity, which will give the translation and angle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This differential equation is related with Frenet-Serret formulas, right? If is not, can you be a little more detailed about that second part?

Comment: @Карпатський Right. The Frenet-Serret formulas are essentially differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can do it constructively. (In fact, it's a bit of both.)

The (signed) curvature of a curve at a point is the number satisfying (with a dot denoting $d/ds$)
$$ \dot{T} = kN, $$
with $T$ the tangent vector $\dot{\alpha}$, and then $N$ is the perpendicular to $T$ taken in the positive direction. To actually do the calculation, we can avoid getting out matrix exponentials and other such perversions by working in complex numbers: if $T=(u,v) = u+iv $, then $N=(-v,u) = -v+iu =iT$, and the equation reads 
$$\dot{T}=ikT.$$
We can then write down the solution as
$$ T = \exp{i\left( \int k(s) \, ds + \varphi \right)}, $$
where $\varphi$ is a constant of integration determined by the initial direction/argument of $T$. Using the definition of $\theta$ in the question, we have, converting back to real vectors by taking real and imaginary parts,
$$ T = (\cos{\theta(s)},\sin{\theta(s)}). $$

You can then apply the uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations to obtain the result (i.e. use that if $\dot{x}(s)=f(s)$, then $x(s)=\int_{s_0}^s f(t) \, dt +x(s_0)$).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I know almost nothing about functions with complex numbers.

Comment: If you prefer, you can think about the matrix $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which acts on vectors $(u,v)$ in the same way that multiplication by $i$ acts on $u+iv$. Then the relevant fact is that the differential equation $v' = kJv$ is solved by $v(t) = \exp{\left(J\int k \, dt\right)} v_0 $, where $\exp{A}$ is the matrix exponential given by $I + A+A^2/2!+A^3/3! + \dotsb$. It is easy to show that for $J$, $\exp{tJ}$ is the rotation matrix $J=\begin{pmatrix} \cos{t} & -\sin{t} \\ \sin{t} &  \cos{t} \end{pmatrix}$, and you get the same result as with complex numbers.